# Word for a person who knows two or three languages

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, prefixes

A *polyglot* is a person who is fluent in many languages, but what do we call a person who is fluent in only two or three languages?

Is *bi-glot* a proper term for this?

I don't think the words *bilingual* / *trilingual* fit the bill, because I am looking for a *-glot* word.

Comment: Can you please explain why *bilingual* doesn't work? It's a bit unclear exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Bilingual can be a noun, so it seems to fit fine.

Comment: @MarkBeadles ... but "bilingual" != "trilingual" ...

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández OP asked for 2 *or* 3.

Comment: @simchona :*Bilingual* is speaking two languages to a high, perhaps native, level.  If you only learn French in school, you are certainly not bilingual.  On the other hand, you are no longer monoglottal, and not yet a polyglot. Good question.

Comment: @MarkBeadles 2 --> bilingual | 3 --> trilingual - A person cannot speak 2 *or* 3 languages!

Comment: @TimLymington The OP doesn't mention native, but *does* refer to being fluent. I'm still unclear as to what he's asking for.

Comment: Wikipedia: "Polyglotism is the ability to speak several languages with a high degree of proficiency. There is no consensus on exactly how many languages a person has to speak to be a polyglot. One could say "four or more", since speakers of two or three languages are commonly called bilingual and trilingual, respectively."

Comment: [*Multilingual*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multilingual) is another possibility, but doesn't exclude the speaker from knowing more than three languages. There is no term I'm aware of that would refer to a group of speakers that are fluent in "only 2 *or* 3" and this distinction may be too arbitrary to warrant a specific term (at least in common use). It would be like asking for a word for someone fluent in "only six or seven" languages. It's a somewhat arbitrary grouping.

Comment: Reminds me of the joke What do you call a person who speaks three languages?  Multilingual.  What do you call a person who speaks two languages? Bilingual.  What do you call a person who speaks one language?  American

Comment: @Gautam: what exactly are you asking then? Fluent? A noun or an adjective? Two words, one for 2 and one for 3, or a single word for exactly from 2 to 3 languages?

Comment: I wonder whether the OP really meant "who is fluent in _only a few_ languages", but instead used the misleadingly precise "two or three". If so, we must therefore exclude compounds that imply fluency in exactly two (or three) languages; we are therefore realistically left with only two single-word possibilities -- _multilingual_ and _polyglot_. There is NO word in English having a precise meaning of "fluent in two or three languages". My personal preference would be _minimally multilingual_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Bi-glot* is wrong, because you’re used the Latin prefix on the Greek suffix.

It should be ***diglot*** (also occasionally spelled *di-glott* in the 19<sup>th</sup> century), which the OED reports is a noun and an adjective meaning:

> Using or containing two languages, bilingual; expressed or written in two languages; also as *sb*. A diglot book or version (cf. **polyglot**).

There is also a corresponding ***triglot*** for three.

Most diglots and triglots are Bibles, not people.

Comment: So biglot would be a diglot word? :)

Comment: @datageist No, it would be *macaronic*.

Comment: di/tri - glot seem to be right .

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglotism) opines that *polyglot* is in fact a valid word in these circumstances, and for a speaker of many languages there is the word *hyperpolyglot*. It also says that for two languages or three languages, *bilingual* and *trilingual* do “fit the bill”. *Multilingual* fits too, although I think I would prefer to reserve that for more than three languages since there is a word *trilingual*.

However, *-lingual* is an adjectival form and you would have to describe someone as being bilingual or *a bilingual person. Bilinguist* doesn’t really work, and nor does *diglot* (you would need the Greek *di-* prefix to use with *-glot*).

One might coin the words *oligoglot* or *paucilinguist* for someone who can speak a few languages, but I don’t think either will catch on.

So if you don't want to use *bilingual* then you are left with *polyglot* and *multilingual*.

Comment: Oxford also attests *bilingual*, n., bilingual person. http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bilingual

Comment: Well of course you **can** use it as a noun, just as you can use *Chinese* as a noun. But "three bilinguals walked into a pub"? Surely not. But whatever: I tend to be conservative.

Comment: Actually, yes. Oxford gives as an example the phrase "Spanish/English bilinguals".

Comment: What I meant by my comment was: Dictionaries attest to previous usage (possibly even only a single occasion). They don't necessarily say what is actually widely used in practice, as we are continually being told in this site. I contend that, OUP notwithstanding, *bilingual* would be distinctly odd as a noun. Perhaps that's another transatlantic difference.

Comment: As someone who lived on the Mexican border for many years, I heard *bilingual* used as a noun a fair number of times. Its use as an adjective was more common, though.

Answer (score 3):

"Trilingual": *adj.* (of a person) speaking three languages fluently (Oxford Dictionary of English).

Merriam-Webster provides a similar definition for "[trilingual](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trilingual)":

> *adj.* familiar with or able to use three languages

Comment: If he is looking for a *-glot* word, Latin isn't going to do it.

Comment: The OP expressly states, "I don't think the word *bilingual* fits the bill", and you give him *trilingual*. Facepalm.

Comment: @ЯegDwight To be fair, from the original question, it wasn't clear whether Gautam was familiar with the term "trilingual" and only afterward did the question explicitly ask for a *-glot* word. I think it was an attempt to fill in the blank since there is no word for someone who knows "only 2 or 3" languages (a person can either know only 2 or only 3) and the word for someone fluent in two languages was already given. Merriam-Webster and Collins English Dictionary define *triglot* as "a book or edition in three languages", but it's easy to extend this to speakers. I gave +1 to both answers.

Answer (score -1):

*Poly* means *many* so technically you could use it for >1.

If you only speak 1 language than you are a monoglot.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks about people who speak exactly two or exactly three languages.