# A single word for a person who can speak many languages

Tags: single-word-requests

Please suggest me a single word for a person who can speak many languages.

Comment: *Multilingual* or *polyglot*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for a person who knows two or three languages](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80638/word-for-a-person-who-knows-two-or-three-languages)

Comment: Multilingual is only an adjective but  I'm looking for a noun . A single one.

Comment: *Polyglot* is both adjective and a noun.

Comment: See above. Polyglot.

Comment: Tks. Polyglot . May be the answer.

Comment: Not *may be*, it *is*.